# New custom field in WSDL

Tags: wsdl

As a C# developer, I use Salesforce's WSDL Web-references to create integrations for the sales department.

Yesterday, they created a new custom field for the leads. I'm supposed to fill it up too.

I downloaded a new WSDL from salesforce, but it doesn't contain the new key.
It contains all the other custom fields.

How can I get it to work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time was the solution.

There was a 2 days delay between the field creation and it's appearance in the WSDL.